# How to make Tcl_WriteChars support Unicode?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, tcl

Is there any initial setup needed to make `Tcl_WriteChars` output UTF-8 characters correctly? e.g.

```
#include <tcl.h>

int main()
{
        Tcl_Interp *tcl = Tcl_CreateInterp();

        Tcl_Channel channel = Tcl_GetStdChannel(TCL_STDOUT);

        Tcl_WriteChars(channel, "hello\n", -1);
        Tcl_WriteChars(channel, "你好\n", -1);
        Tcl_WriteRaw(channel, "你好\n", -1);

        Tcl_Close(tcl, channel);

        Tcl_DeleteInterp(tcl);

        return 0;
}
```

Source code is saved in UTF-8 encoding, and following output is from UTF-8 locale Linux:

```
hello
??
你好
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the encoding to be UTF-8 (and the host you're running on appears to be using something else for its default). Do this before you write to the channel.

```c
Tcl_SetChannelOption(interp, channel, "-encoding", "utf-8");
```

Properly, you should check for the return code of that (as below) but all channels have that option and the `utf-8` encoding is baked directly into Tcl, so it won't fail.

```c
if (Tcl_SetChannelOption(interp, channel, "-encoding", "utf-8") != TCL_OK) {
    return TCL_ERROR;
}
```

---

[EDIT]: Having re-read the code a little more carefully (and found out that the system's default encoding is really UTF-8 in the first place), the *actual* problem is that you're not calling `Tcl_FindExecutable()`. That routine is a bit mis-named, as what it actually does (apart from making `info nameofexecutable` work inside scripts) is let Tcl initialise its internal library. In particular, it initialises the encoding management subsystem, and that's the point where it works out what the system encoding really is (otherwise it falls back to `iso8859-1`, which is the least problematic ordinary encoding to recover from).

Your code should read:

```
#include <tcl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    /// <<<< CHANGED HERE
{
    Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);   /// <<<< CHANGED HERE

    Tcl_Interp *tcl = Tcl_CreateInterp();

    Tcl_Channel channel = Tcl_GetStdChannel(TCL_STDOUT);

    Tcl_WriteChars(channel, "hello\n", -1);
    Tcl_WriteChars(channel, "你好\n", -1);
    Tcl_WriteRaw(channel, "你好\n", -1);

    Tcl_Close(tcl, channel);

    Tcl_DeleteInterp(tcl);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming you're using a compiler that is happy with putting declarations after statements. That's a widely-implemented C99 feature (and is also in C++) so I expect it will be fine.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I have checked with `Tcl_GetChannelOption` in my host, which returns `iso8859-1`. Really strange, as I have set my host locale to UTF-8.

Comment: Oh! I just realised what the problem is! You never call `Tcl_FindExecutable`; that matters as that is what works out what the system encoding actually is.

Comment: I also noticed that `tclsh` do not have this problem, as it will call `TclpSetInitialEncodings` (which `Tcl_FindExecutable` also relys on) in `Tcl_MainEx`. BTW, I'm curious that why `TclpSetInitialEncodings` is not called in `TclInitEncodingSubsystem`? Which seems to be a more suitable place. That function will be called by `TclInitSubsystems`, which is called both by `Tcl_FindExecutable` and `Tcl_CreateInterp`. As I'm embedding Tcl into another system, and `argv0` is not exposed to its extension system, so `Tcl_FindExecutable` can not be called.

Comment: You can pass `NULL` instead of `argv[0]`. It means that `info nameofexecutable` might be wrong (depending on how good the platform's internal guessing heuristics are) but it does initialise the encodings and the standard channels correctly. (They're separate because there's an evil ordering dependency, IIRC.)